# List comprenehsion that gets regex to be executed

Tags: python, list

I don't know what's wrong with this. I have a list of items:

```
int=['xe-0/1/1', 'xe-0/1/2', 'xe-0/1/3', 'xe-0/2/2', 'xe-0/2/3', 'xe-0/3/1', 'xe-1/0/2', 'xe-1/0/3', 'xe-1/1/1', 'xe-1/1/2', 'xe-1/2/2', 'xe-1/2/3', 'xe-1/3/1', 'xe-1/3/2', 'xe-2/0/2', 'xe-2/0/3', 'xe-2/1/1', 'xe-2/1/2', 'xe-2/1/3', 'xe-2/2/2', 'xe-2/2/3', 'xe-2/3/1', 'xe-2/3/2', 'xe-3/0/2', 'xe-3/0/3', 'xe-3/1/2', 'xe-3/1/3', 'xe-3/2/1', 'xe-3/2/2', 'xe-3/2/3', 'xe-3/3/2', 'xe-4/0/2', 'xe-4/0/3', 'xe-4/1/2', 'xe-4/1/3', 'xe-4/2/2', 'xe-4/2/3', 'xe-4/3/2', 'xe-4/3/3', 'xe-7/3/3', 'xe-8/0/7', 'xe-8/3/6', 'xe-8/3/7', 'xe-9/0/5', 'xe-9/0/6', 'xe-9/0/7', 'xe-9/1/5', 'xe-9/1/6', 'xe-10/0/4', 'xe-10/0/6', 'xe-10/0/7', 'xe-10/1/6', 'xe-10/2/4', 'xe-10/2/6', 'xe-10/2/7', 'xe-10/3/7', 'xe-11/0/6', 'xe-11/0/7', 'xe-11/1/6', 'xe-11/1/7', 'xe-11/2/6', 'xe-11/2/7', 'xe-11/3/6', 'xe-11/3/7']
```

and I want to iterate this list and get two new lists that contains only a match that I define in the regex.

```
for i in range(2):
    regex="xe-%s/1/*" %i
    print regex
    [x for x in int if re.match(r'regex',x)]
```

> Result:
>
> xe-0/1/* [] xe-1/1/* []

But it seems that doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post your desired output?

Comment: You are searching for the literal string "regex"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you want the expression stored in `regex`, not the string "regex":

```
regex="xe-%s/1/*" %i

[x for x in numbers if re.match(regex,x)]
```

Note the the variable name `int` has to be changed to something else, in this case `numbers`, because `int` is a built in function and will throw an error when the code is run.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong here - but I believe that this will recompile the regular expression every time the `if` statement is called ie for every item in `numbers`. If this is the case you should consider compiling the pattern first, and then using `pattern.match(x)`

Comment: Yeah, worked now. Thanks alot 

for i in range(2):
    regex="xe-%s/1/*" %i
    [x for x in int if re.match(regex,x)]

Comment: @TomWyllie you are correct. However, I did try to emulate the OP's code as closely as possible.

Comment: @MohamedKamal glad to help!